# How to grab data from plain text response of API Calls in PHP?

Tags: php, api, curl, text

I'm getting API response in plain text. I need to grab data from that text response and need to store them as variables.

API Calling:

```
  $url="http://91.101.61.111:99/SendRequest/?mobile=9999999999&id=11011&reqref=501";
  $request_timeout = 60;
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $request_timeout);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $request_timeout);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $output = curl_exec($ch);
  $curl_error = curl_errno($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
```

API response in plain text:

```
REQUEST ACCEPTED your ref=501 system_reference=BA01562
```

I need to grab data from the above plain text response as variables, like below:

```
$status = "REQUEST ACCEPTED";  
$myref = "501";  
$sysref = "BA01562";
```

I have tried:

```
$explode1 = explode(" ", $output);      
$explode2 = explode("=", $explode1[3]);
$explode3 = explode("=", $explode1[4]);

$status = $explode1[0]." ".$explode1[1];
$myref = $explode2[1];
$sysref = $explode3[1];
```

I know this is not a proper way to do this. But I am not able to figure out the proper way to do it since I'm a newbie.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: Start parsing. What did you try?

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: You should experiment with the API a bit (or check its documentation if that exists, or both) first, and see what other kinds of responses you might get, so you can know how to parse it. If the different possible responses aren't consistently structured, you'll need to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a preg_match, something like:

```
$rc = preg_match('/([\w\s]+) your ref=([\d]+) system_reference=([\w]+)/', $plain_response, $matches);
if ($rc)
{
    $status = $matches[1];  
    $myref = $matches[2];  
    $sysref = $matches[3];  
}
```

but of course, just as @Don't panic said, you need a bit more knowledge of the API, to be sure about parsing. The example i gived is a bit childish. Anyway, when you will be sure about the format, use regexp with preg_match.